I couldn't able to insert a record in Catalyst table through Catalyst API
I am facing "INVALID OAUTH TOKEN" while inserting a new record into a Catalyst Datastore table using Catalyst API.
{
"status": "failure",
"data": {
"error_code": "INVALID_TOKEN",
"message": "invalid oauth token"
}
}
This is the error, i'm getting while invoking the insert a row api.

The error "INVALID OAUTH TOKEN" you are facing while trying to insert a record using Catalyst API might occur if the access token might have expired. The access token will only be accessible for one hour(3600 seconds) from the time it has been generated. Hence, you can generate a new access_token using the refresh token and then, try hitting the insert a row API with new access token. You can find their help documentation here to generate a new access token.
